# Content by using AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

We are using following code for displaying html text in a dynamic classic text field.

```
var txtFld = new TextField();

txtFld.x = 10;

txtFld.y = 0;

txtFld.wordWrap = txtFld.multiline = true;

txtFld.width = 1190;

txtFld.autoSize= "left";

txtFld.embedFonts = true;

txtFld.antiAliasType=AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;

txtFld.htmlText  = (Dynamic text);
```

If using "Normal"  AntiAliasType instead of Advanced then everything is working fine. But text quality of application is not good, so i have used "AntiAliasType.ADVANCED" to make the text quality better.

We are getting lots of problem by using "AntiAliasType.ADVANCED" like visibility of text with long text, not able to embed the "GGSubscript" font etc.

Also if I user flash player version 10.3 or above then the text is also visible but the fonts are not embedded in it.

I have tried number of flash player version. Please suggest if this can be correctly some how.

Thanks,

Ashmesh Thakur